# Installing PDO in amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdo

im trying to install simple app in Amazon AWS. Since im really new to servers i used Elastic Beanstalk.

Everythink ok, but when i run my app i get an error: PDO error: could not find driver.
I tried mysqli_ping the connection and got boolean true, so this is OK.

I checked for help, but all i found is here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html

2.If you plan to use PDO, install the PDO drivers. For more information, go to http://www.php.net/manual/pdo.installation.php.

But i really don't know what to do with this information. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

so, its quite a procedure, first you have to get ssh access to your instance:

**1. Generate key value for you instance & download it in pem format.**

- go to: https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=eu-west-1#Instances (change for your region)

  - click Key Pairs, Create Key pairs and create your new key par and download it to you comp.
  - assosiate your instance with the key, go to elastic beanstalk, select you application, select configuration, instances and select your new key from drop-down of EC2 key pair.

**2. download putty for windows (installer) & install it:** http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

**3. Transform key to .pkk format using PuTTYgen:**
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/connect-to-amazon-ec2-with-a-private-key-using-putty-and-pageant/?tag=nl.e011#.

**4. Setup putty to use key:** http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-deploy-app-connect.html

**5. run putty and find you instance public dns** and add ec2-user in front of it, so it looks like this: ec2-user@ec2-54-76-47-0.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Then is as simple as: yum install php-pdo

Comment: Note that if you do this, your instance will not contain the PDO driver if replaced by EB. You should use Container Commands to automatically install PDO when booting.